# EF core 7 is not allowing to map multiple properties of an entity with single database column whereas it was working in earlier EF Core versions

Tags: ef-core-7.0

Earlier I had mapped multiple properties with single db column as below and it was working. Now after upgrading to EF Core 7, it's showing error: both properties mapped to column 'variableName' in 'ApplicationVariables', but the properties are contained within the same hierarchy. All properties on an entity type must be mapped to unique different columns.'"

Is there any work around for this in EF Core 7?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationVariable>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
    entity.Property(e => e.Id)
        .HasColumnName("variableName")
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(150)
        .IsUnicode(false);

    entity.Property(e => e.VariableName)
        .HasColumnName("variableName")
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(150)
        .IsUnicode(false);
});
```